# Redirect according to views filter input

Tags: views

I have a view with two filters (country and city) on node (country) page. What I want is redirect to another node page according to user input (filter country). So if user viewing page node/uk and chooses USA in country filter and New York in city filter, drupal must redirect to page node/usa showing results for New York. View is using AJAX.
Tried using drupal_goto in views exposed form submit but this produces error `Drupal.Views.Ajax.handleErrors is not a function` in ajax_view.js. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) on the exposed filter form.
It is very well explained [in this post](http://www.opensourcecatholic.com/blog/archstl/drupal-views-filters-mak).
A [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto) depending on the input entered should work.